# Composer error when uninstalling the extension

Tags: shopware6

I have an extension, where I have the composer dependency execution active. During the uninstall process, the `api/notification/message` endpoint returns the following error:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/shop/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/shop/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 41

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/shop/vendor/composer/../phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/shop/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:41 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/shop/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(45): {closure}('decc78cc4436b12...', '/var/www/shop/v...') #1 /var/www/shop/vendor/autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInitf1d3e0a8bbcc0b4c05643c8805746192::getLoader() #2 /var/www/shop/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(5): require_once('/var/www/shop/v...') #3 /var/www/shop/public/index.php(14): require_once('/var/www/shop/v...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/shop/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 41
```

This leads to error alerts like "n is undefined" for the admin user.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue within Shopware itself and should be fixed with this commit:
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/commit/36f16279f97ffe3c541635b3476025cebf6873b5